# loop exiting prematurely in PHP

Tags: php

I want to create a loop to insert multiple records when executed. The intend is to easily create a full database for testing purpose. Below is the loop I have written however the problem is the loop exits prematurely stopping around 30-something.

```
$i = 0;
$numberOfRecords = 100;
$uploadedBy = "guest";
$uploadedWhen = date("Ymd");
$picture = "image";
$alt = "lorum ipsum";
$additionalInfo = "hello world";

set_time_limit(0);
while($i <= $numberOfRecords){
    $varName = 'guest'.$i;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO images(id, uploadedBy, uploadedWhen, picture, alt, additionalInfo) 
        VALUES ('$i', '$varName', '$uploadedWhen', 'pictures/$picture', '$alt', '$additionalInfo')")        OR DIE("something died");
    echo $i;
    $i++;
}
```

so question boils down to, Why is my code exiting at 30-40 rows(currently the code adds 2 iterations to the loop at every refresh)?
thanks for the replies in advance.
NOTE: I know I shouldn't be using    mysql_query, but this is just a hastily written draft that will undergo some fine tuning after the loop issue has been resolved ^^

EDIT: clarification; the code runs for a few iterations and then jumps to the OR DIE statement.
EDIT2: Removing the OR DIE statement resolved the loop issues, HOWEVER interesting is that record 42 has $i at value 0; if anyone would care to explain I'd appreciate that.

Comment: You mean it exits as in stops or gives an error?

Comment: Please put on error_reporting and show us what errors you are getting displayed.

Comment: @darrenSweeney it runs for a few iteration and then jumps to the OR DIE statement

Comment: Then I suggest you add the SQL query to your die message and that way you can see what caused it

Comment: Try keeping the id field as INT(10) and make it Primary key with Auto Increment in the table.

Comment: 42 is the meaning of life and everything... not an answer, just an observation ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Using id as type integer in table

$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO test.images(id, uploadedBy, uploadedWhen, picture, alt, additionalInfo) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", $i, $varName, $uploadedWhen, 'pictures/'.$picture, $alt, $additionalInfo);
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("dies");

2. Using id as varchar

you may use the original code.

Comment: i personally checked this code. wonder why this was down voted.